# addImage {ReporteRs} height and width commands not working

Tags: r, image, ms-word, reporters

I'm populating a docx with some images using the addImage function, which has parameters for width and height of the image. However no matter what I seem to do, these numbers do not stick, the image is inserted at its original size.

To reproduce it you'll need to create a docx, add a bookmark in it somewhere called "image_bookmark" (insert>bookmark), and save the docx into your WD as "input.docx". Also you'll need an (png) image in that folder, rename it "image".

```
docx.file = "output.docx")
doc = docx(template= "input.docx")
doc = addImage( doc = doc , filename = "image.png",width = 6.88, height = 2, bookmark = "image_bookmark") 
writeDoc( doc, docx.file )
```

I've attached the actual image I am working with. I want it's width to be ~17.49cm (page width in word), it keeps coming out as ~20 regardless of width parameter.

[image: image.png]

Comment: First, why don't you create a full reproducible example like `library(ReporteRs); for (x in 1:3) { mydoc = docx(); img.file = file.path( Sys.getenv("R_HOME"), "doc", "html", "logo.jpg" ); doc <- addImage(mydoc, img.file, width = 1.4*x, height = 1, par.properties = parLeft() ); writeDoc( mydoc, file = tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".docx")); message(tf) }`. Second, the dimension parameters seem to work here; I use ReporteRs_0.7.8, ReporteRsjars_0.0.2.

Comment: @lukeA
Thanks for the tip, I am very new to R and was not aware of things like the logo.jpg residing in the home folder, nor some of the basic functions like sys.getenv or the tf procedure you've used. Thus, I hoped to create a reproducible example with my simple instructions. 

Curious that it works for you, at least the package is working as intended. I'll keep digging. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and had the same versions as @lukeA, which are currently the most recent.

I found a work-around that might do the trick if you are still having this issue. I noticed that changing the ppi in the function call altered the image size added into the .docx file. In windows, I opened the .png image properties to find out the file's pixels per inch, which was quite high because I had wanted to produce a high-resolution image. So to resize the image, all I did was figure out how many pixels per inch would shrink the image to the size I wanted, and entered this into the ppi part of the call.